# i am trying to remove previously added row to a jtable when initializing a jcombobox

Tags: if-statement, jtable, jcombobox

```
   if(comboBox.getSelectedItem() == itemname) {
                        
                         
                         model.addRow(row);
                    }else {
                        comboBox.setSelectedItem("Enter Item");
                    }
```

``I am trying use if statement to solve my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The if statement should help avoid updatetable() method when initialized from adding a row in jtable before an item is selected in jcombobox. An item should be added only when item is selected.